# Sum value XSLT in List View SharePoint Designer return 0

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a list with the ammount value, and I have to sum it. The webpart list is inside another display list view.

```
=================
Ammount / Valor
1111
14515
=================
```

The "Ammount / Valor" is number type.

When I try to use XSLT in SharePoint Designer:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Ammount_x0020__x002f__x0020_Valo.), &quot;#,##0.;-#,##0.&quot;)" />
```

Works beautiful in Design view, but when I go browser, the value is 0!

**In Design View**

[image]

**In the browser**

[image]

Comment: Can you add the source XML and the complete XSL stylesheet showing that in context?

Comment: Seems silly, I know, but have you tried without the encoded quotes - as someone who works with XSLT & SharePoint data a lot, it wouldn't be the first time something wonky like that differed between SPD & the browser. So do your format-number as: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Ammount_x0020__x002f__x0020_Valo.), '#,##0.;-#,##0.')" />

Comment: I am quite surprised that the name of the attribute ends with a `.`: `@Ammount_x0020__x002f__x0020_Valo.`. It also contains a lot of escaped characters. Possibly the attribute is not matched in the browser because the browser does not recognize it as a valid name (i.e., ignores the dot). But without the input XML and a more complete XSLT that illustrates the issue there is little we can do to to help you. Check out [ask].